# Optimize linq query for .FindIndex

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, asp.net-core

I have method to get index of with condition

Here is code for it

```
public async Task<int> GetJobSupplierRank(Guid? jobId, string supplierKey, UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum type,
        Guid? useCaseId)
    {
        List<VwJobSupplierWithScore> suppliersList;
        int rankPair;
        switch (type)
        {
            case UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum.Score:
                rankPair = await GetScoreRankForJobSupplier(jobId, supplierKey, useCaseId);
                break;
            case UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum.Spend:
                suppliersList = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores.OrderBy(x => x.SpendValueCurrencyJob)
                    .ToListAsync();
                rankPair = suppliersList.FindIndex(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey);
                break;
            case UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum.Invoices:
                suppliersList = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores.OrderBy(x => x.InvoiceValueCurrencyJob)
                    .ToListAsync();
                rankPair = suppliersList.FindIndex(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey);
                break;
            case UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum.POs:
                suppliersList = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
                    .OrderBy(x => x.PurchaseOrderValueCurrencyJob).ToListAsync();
                rankPair = suppliersList.FindIndex(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey);
                break;
            case UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum.Payments:
                suppliersList = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores.OrderBy(x => x.PaymentValueCurrencyJob)
                    .ToListAsync();
                rankPair = suppliersList.FindIndex(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(type));
        }

        return rankPair;
    }
```

I have 100K+ rows in views and this `.FindIndex(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey)` working extremely slow.

How I can speed up it?

Comment: Instead of loading all 100k records into this in-memory list and then search the index, why don't you select just the single rank-value from the database?

Comment: @TimSchmelter How I can do this?

Comment: To answer this question, or even begin giving suggestions, it's crucial to know what `GetScoreRankForJobSupplier` and `FindIndex` do. Probably more than just getting a rank that could be obtained in SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold I need to get position of element by `x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey`

So this will be Rank

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @GertArnold `FindIndex` is `List<T>.FindIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say how performant this would be, and it assumes that the `OrderBy` keys generate a unique ordering (if not, you have a problem anyway), but you can count the rows that come before your matching row and use that to get the Rank:

```
case UseCaseMetricsTypesEnum.Spend:
    rankPair = await
                _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
                    .Where(j => j.JobId == jobId && j.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
                    .Select(wantedJ => _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores.Where(j => j.SpendValueCurrencyJob < wantedJ.SpendValueCurrencyJob).Count()+1)
                    .FirstAsync();
    break;
```